# Why are there multi PageHeader?

Tags: excel, jasper-reports

I use a *JasperReports* report, with a filled *Detail* band

Now, my reports have many PageHeader.

I want to know how to print one pageheader

I upload this *jasper* file as an XML File.

**Now My reports.excel**

*PageHeader*
data1
data2
data3
data4
data5
data6
data7
*PageHeader*
data8
data9
data10
data11
.
.
.

**Wanted My reports.excel**

*PageHeader*
data1
data2
data3
data4
data5
data6
data7
data8
data9
data10
data11
.
.
.

reports.jrxml

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report" language="groovy" pageWidth="1200" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="1160" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="1df9fdbc-78fc-4ea3-bbce-af5a714f699d">
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT
    DEPT_CODE,
    CASE
        WHEN PROJECT_SEQ = 0 THEN '-'
        ELSE (SELECT
                P.PRJ_NAME
            FROM
                PROJECT P
            WHERE
                P.SEQ = PROJECT_SEQ)
    END AS PROJECT_NAME,
    IFNULL(CASE
            WHEN SALES_DEPT IS NULL THEN '-'
            ELSE (SELECT
                    CODE_DETAIL_NAME
                FROM
                    CODE_DETAIL
                WHERE
                    CODE_GROUP_GROUP_CODE = 'DEPT_CODE'
                        AND CODE_DETAIL = SALES_DEPT)
        END, '-') AS SALES_DEPT_NM,
    IFNULL(CASE WHEN SALES_ID IS NULL THEN '-'
        ELSE (SELECT
                USR.NAME
            FROM
                USR
            WHERE USR.USR_ID = MONTHLY_BIZ_HISTORY.SALES_ID)
        END, '-') AS SALES_NAME,
    ACCEPT,
    TL_ACCEPT,
    EXPENSE_REQUEST,
    SUPPORT_TYPE,
    IFNULL(CASE
            WHEN COMPANY_SEQ IS NULL THEN '-'
            ELSE (SELECT
                    COMP_NAME
                FROM
                    COMPANY
                WHERE
                    COMPANY.SEQ = MONTHLY_BIZ_HISTORY.COMPANY_SEQ)
        END, '-') AS COMP_NAME,
    (SELECT
            NAME
        FROM
            USR U
        WHERE
            U.USR_ID = MONTHLY_BIZ_HISTORY.USR_ID) AS USR_NAME,
    IFNULL((SELECT
            CODE_DETAIL_NAME
        FROM
            CODE_DETAIL
        WHERE
            CODE_GROUP_GROUP_CODE = 'WORK_POSITION'
                AND CODE_DETAIL = WORK_POSITION), '-') AS WORK_POSITION_NAME,
    ROUND(WORK_DAYS / AWD.WORK_AVAIL, 2) AS WORK_DAY,
    SUPPORT_RATE,
    FORMAT(UNIT_COST, 0) AS UNIT_COST,
    FORMAT(PARTIAL_SALES, 0) AS PARTIAL_SALES,
    WORK_DAYS
FROM
    MONTHLY_BIZ_HISTORY,
    (SELECT COUNT(SUBSTRING(WORK_DATE, 1, 6)) WORK_AVAIL
      FROM AVAILABLE_WORK_DAYS
     WHERE PROJECT_SEQ ='0'
       AND WORK_DATE LIKE CONCAT('201405', '%')
       AND WORK_AVAIL = 'Y') AS AWD
WHERE
    BIZ_MONTH = '201405'
    AND DEPT_CODE = 'AF0010'
ORDER BY EXPENSE_REQUEST, PARTIAL_SALES DESC]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="deptCode" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="projectName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="salesDeptNm" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="salesName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="accept" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="tlAccept" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="expenseRequest" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="supportType" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="compName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="usrName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="workPositionName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="workDay" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="supportRate" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="unitCost" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="partialSales" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="workDays" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <elementGroup>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="414" y="15" width="290" height="49" uuid="bb55513e-c9c1-45ff-88ba-01cf8e09e213"/>
                    <box>
                        <topPen lineWidth="1.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="나눔바른고딕" size="24" isItalic="true" pdfFontName="NanumBarunGothic.ttf" pdfEncoding="Identity-H"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[내부거래관리]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </elementGroup>
            <image>
                <reportElement x="1024" y="27" width="112" height="37" uuid="cd4ea1b6-66e0-41bb-8883-1f6cc7f08455"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="2.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="2.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="2.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="2.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="2.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA["C:\\Users\\dwlee\\Desktop\\kcc로고.gif"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="51" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="51" height="51" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="4ea19576-d048-41f0-9af9-14c63ef3959e"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[영업팀]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="51" y="0" width="43" height="51" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="9cd8b7ac-de41-493d-849a-bd3843070175"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[영업
대표]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="93" y="0" width="41" height="51" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="3711e33b-cd0f-4d37-b380-5bea98750583"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[영업
승인]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="134" y="0" width="40" height="51" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="74926a4e-5050-43d0-b7bd-7febef10fd2f"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[팀장
승인]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="174" y="0" width="37" height="51" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="a263afee-4593-483d-9198-2d91665b33b7"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[비용
청구]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="210" y="0" width="39" height="51" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="d2cd8c4a-1bf7-484a-aad8-880f558fe0c8"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[지원
형태]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="249" y="0" width="131" height="51" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="3b463282-36e9-49f3-9080-8d37624708bd"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[고객]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="380" y="0" width="51" height="51" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="fd076787-8c4d-4b93-b2f1-2435184c1669"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[참여자]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="431" y="0" width="51" height="51" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="4d7c9d78-7265-4fbe-b5be-766e42347afc"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[직급]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="482" y="0" width="41" height="51" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="657fc6fa-1ffd-4e84-9711-cebd2121f510"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[공수]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="523" y="0" width="43" height="51" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="dc02b109-b8a7-4782-89b9-43ce530a9738"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[지원
효율]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="566" y="0" width="394" height="51" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="3407be15-5c27-4811-b21f-875dd5f80e00"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[프로젝트명/비고]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="960" y="0" width="64" height="51" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="ef5eb302-7ca1-4ef7-8859-43914e8da889"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[단가(원)]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="1024" y="0" width="64" height="51" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="7b7bb7f5-b38b-4a16-84dd-00852b82b3b3"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[매출(원)]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="1088" y="0" width="72" height="51" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="375e8c42-0819-4fe6-84a8-0b271fdb0577"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[근무일수]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="41" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="51" y="0" width="42" height="41" uuid="aa36ca90-fc22-467a-b94b-a713f2cfeca4"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{salesName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="51" height="41" uuid="3b804ce6-5107-422a-b068-30dfac3ba330"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{salesDeptNm}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="94" y="0" width="40" height="41" uuid="d95e87d2-20a7-4bc2-96d0-ec01a269a822"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{accept}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="134" y="0" width="40" height="41" uuid="eaef3355-161d-4427-b8ae-73e64b231841"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{tlAccept}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="174" y="0" width="36" height="41" uuid="815ebd12-f601-4a65-bf4e-2b0345b4d634"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{expenseRequest}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="210" y="0" width="39" height="41" uuid="6d5792f0-e3e3-4fa7-be13-6337fa99e10b"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{supportType}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="380" y="0" width="51" height="41" uuid="38f52444-ad20-4edd-b81b-fb9677dbbe1f"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{usrName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="249" y="0" width="131" height="41" uuid="b09f1811-847c-4eea-ba70-ad90c9278aff"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{compName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="431" y="0" width="51" height="41" uuid="28ffa70e-fc8c-4814-9529-010d203a265c"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{workPositionName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="482" y="0" width="41" height="41" uuid="1fb8daa8-8c88-43e9-8bdf-d48b9a276547"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{workDay}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="960" y="0" width="64" height="41" uuid="e7250e89-6fcb-44f5-8069-e3ab00753699"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{unitCost}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="566" y="0" width="394" height="41" uuid="c45e336e-8fdf-4b58-abb2-53297c8b5015"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{projectName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="523" y="0" width="43" height="41" uuid="b5fb61d6-9eb7-465a-b9af-f3829294c79d"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{supportRate}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="1024" y="0" width="64" height="41" uuid="ebc395a2-a9d3-4171-ac97-c5faf9ec04d7"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{partialSales}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="1088" y="0" width="72" height="41" uuid="aad889e4-d441-441f-8a09-74dd69cccf4f"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{workDays}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="55" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: What did you try, what happened, what did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the `isIgnorePagination` flag solves your issue. This is a attribute at report level and can be set like this:

```
<jasperReport ... isIgnorePagination="true" ...> 
... 
</jasperReport>
```

From the [jasper docs](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/nopagebreak/index.html):

> In the case where no batch export is implied, all document pages share the same page settings, and they are by default separated by page breaks. At export time each exporter has its own way to handle the page break element in order to make visible the page separation.
>
> But there are situations, especially for web-oriented applications, where pagination is irrelevant and it causes the document to be displayed improperly. For instance, when exporting documents to HTML format, one might prefer to display it as a continuous scrollable page rather than a succession of pages separated by visible empty spaces. Or, when exporting to Excel in a single sheet document, a layout without visible page breaks would be preferred.